# my docker build just keeps closing

Tags: docker

i'm on OS X 10.9 and am using docker v0.7. i'm using the following docker file: https://gist.github.com/jonathanong/7366257. i've `vagrant up; vagrant ssh; sudo docker build .` the Dockerfile.

when i'm building, everything is fine until almost the end. then i get this error:

[image]

anyone know what's going on or how i can debug this?

EDIT: got a new error:

[image]

probably something unrelated to Docker. i'll open a new question for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. the process just kept getting closed because my VM didn't have enough memory. bumped the memory from 384mb (default for virtual box i guess) to 512mb and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, you can just take an image from a successful intermediate step and start it with `-i -t ... /bin/bash`. Then try doing what you're doing manually and see what happens.

Note that in your Dockerfile, you want to download and clean up after unpacking the tar file in the same RUN command. Now, you clean up only at the end, which makes your diffs (und thus, the intermediate images) unnecessaryly big.

Comment: ooo yeah i'll change that. plus one less RUN command is nice.